# C# - Writing a header to a log file using string builder

Tags: c#, string, file, logging, builder

This should be an extremely easy fix, but for some reason I am missing something. All I am trying to do is get the String Builder function that I have to write the header, but for some reason it isnt currently.

When I try to change the if statement to !File.Exists(tempFileName), it does not run through my loop.

Any suggestions? Also, let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void Open(string tempFileName, string division,
                             int zipFiles, int conversions, int returnedFiles, int totalEmails)
    {
        StreamWriter dailyStats;

        //This is where I am missing something
        //I am passing in the original filename of a log, then adding "-Stats.log"
        //so I can tell the difference between what is the new stats file, and the original log file
        if (File.Exists(tempFileName))
        {
            dailyStats = new StreamWriter(tempFileName + "-Stats.log");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("Division");
            sb.Append("\t");
            sb.Append("Zip Files");
            sb.Append("\t");
            sb.Append("Conversions");
            sb.Append("\t");
            sb.Append("Returned Files");
            sb.Append("\t");
            sb.Append("Total E-Mails");
            sb.Append("\t");

        }
        else
        {
            dailyStats = File.AppendText(tempFileName + "-Stats.log");
        }

        if (writeLog)
        {
            //Use a string builder to assemble the content for performance reasons
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            s.Append(division);
            s.Append("\t");
            s.Append(zipFiles);
            s.Append("\t");
            s.Append(conversions);
            s.Append("\t");
            s.Append(returnedFiles);
            s.Append("\t");
            s.Append(totalEmails);
            s.Append("\t");

            dailyStats.WriteLine(s.ToString());
        }

        dailyStats.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it like this

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
string logFileName = tempFileName + "-Stats.log";
if (File.Exists(logFileName)) {
    dailyStats = File.AppendText(logFileName); 
} else {
    dailyStats = new StreamWriter(logFileName); 

    // Write header
    sb.Append("Division");
    ...
    sb.AppendLine();
} 

if (writeLog)  {
    sb.Append(division);
    ...
    dailyStats.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
} 
dailyStats.Close();
```

---

**UPDATE**

The code had different errors. Two `StringBuilders` were created, but only one was written to the file. The existence of the file was determined for a different file name than the actual file that was written to. And finally, the logic depending on the existence of the file was inverted. I rewrote and refactored the code completely, in order to make it more understandable and manageable

```
public static void Open(string tempFileName, string division,
                     int zipFiles, int conversions, int returnedFiles, int totalEmails)
{
    if (!writeLog)
        return;

    using (StreamWriter dailyStats = OpenLogFile(tempFileName)) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(division);
        // ...
        dailyStats.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}

private static StreamWriter OpenLogFile(string tempFileName)
{
    StreamWriter dailyStats;
    string logFileName = tempFileName + "-Stats.log";
    if (File.Exists(logFileName)) {
        dailyStats = File.AppendText(logFileName);
    } else {
        dailyStats = new StreamWriter(logFileName);
        WriteHeader(dailyStats);
    }
    return dailyStats;
}

private static void WriteHeader(StreamWriter dailyStats)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Division");
    // ...
    dailyStats.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Note: The using statement closes the file and releases the external resources automatically.

Comment: I do like this code better than my previous code, but as I mentioned in a comment in the answer above, it is still not working for some reason. Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: The `if` and the `else` part have to be exchanged. You want to write the header only if the file did not yet exist, i.e. only into new files. (I changed it in my example now.)

Comment: This does in fact write out the header, but now its only running through my loop and printing the values one time. For some reason whenever I change one thing, I get the other and vice versa. Cannot figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I do not see where the `writeLog` variable is set. Is ist set to `false` somewhere?

Comment: writeLog is set to true as a static member variable, I did not include it in the question originally, but it is in the code

Comment: Another error is, that you check for the existance of `tempFileName` but then write to `tempFileName + "-Stats.log"`! (I changed that too.)

Answer (score 5):

Are you not missing code in the first block?:

```
dailyStats.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Thus:

```
    if (File.Exists(tempFileName))
    {
        dailyStats = new StreamWriter(tempFileName + "-Stats.log");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Division");
        sb.Append("\t");
        sb.Append("Zip Files");
        sb.Append("\t");
        sb.Append("Conversions");
        sb.Append("\t");
        sb.Append("Returned Files");
        sb.Append("\t");
        sb.Append("Total E-Mails");
        sb.Append("\t");

        // Add this ......
        dailyStats.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I apologize, I did in fact have that code, I just did not paste it by accident. However, this still for some reason is not solving my issue. I am still either getting this result: a) The header is being printed but its only running through my loop once. b) The header is not being printed and my loop is being run full through

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a second `StringBuilder` and not doing anything with it.  You probably want to just define the `StringBuilder` at a higher level so that appending to it in either block all adds it to one SB which can be written out at the end.

The other option of course is to write out the contents of the `StringBuilder` used to write the header to `dailyStats` rather than just doing nothing with it after appending the strings.